# How to convert cursor list to JSON format in python?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I am receiving an output like [<ColletionName: ColletionName object>]. But when I try using json dumps and loads as shown below, it returns only the heading of the table and not along with the body.

```
   return loads(dumps(cursor))
```

This returns only the table headers and not along with the value.
How to get the complete values in JSON format from cursor list using python/pymongo?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the cursor to a list:

```
return loads(dumps(list(cursor)))
```

Comment: This too returns only the headers in a list

Comment: How is `cursor` created?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for loop.

```
for i in cursor_list:
    print i.id (the header)
```